# Find the Last Column which contains values in a Specific Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 3 Normal Data Ranges from A3:O43, Q3:AE43, AG3:AU43, and all these cells are filled with formulas.

Now I would like to identify the last column of each range based on Values using FIND or any other way. I have tried using the below code, but I'm not able to get the column numbers properly.

```
With UBMonthlyYTDSht
    Set Rowss = .Columns("B:B").Find("*", After:=.Range("B1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not Rowss Is Nothing Then Lrows = Rowss.Row
End With

Lcols = UBMonthlyYTDSht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With UBMonthlyYTDSht
    Set Colss = .Rows(Lrows).Find("*", After:=.Cells(Lrows, Lcols), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not Colss Is Nothing Then Lcols = Colss.Column
End With
```

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: Using `After:=.Cells(Lrows, 1)` might make a difference. Depends on what you mean by "I'm not able to get the column numbers properly".

Comment: I would like to identify the Last Column with VALUES for multiple ranges. Is there any way to identify?

Comment: Your code refers to a single row.

Comment: Now I have mentioned the additional code which I'm able to achieve the Last Column with only VALUES, only if I have 1 dataset like A2:P63, but the same technique is not working if we have multiple datasets in a single sheet-like mentioned in the above question

Comment: Are you expecting one number or 3? Do you need the worksheet column number or the number that represents the n-th column of a range?

Comment: I'm trying to identify the Last Column in a specific Range that contains only VALUES in a specific Row.

for eg: I have formulas placed in A2:P63 cells, now I wanted to get the last column of row 27 that has got results from these formulas. And the formula has resulted values in A, B, C & D columns, now my Last Column count has to be 4 and if get results in A,B,C,D & E then last column result has to be 5

Comment: Where do you want the results, e.g. in an array, in another sheet in the range "A3:C43"...?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying identify the coordinates like LasrRow and LastColumn in the specific Range and using that specific range in Charts

Answer (score 0):

### Reference Top Left Non-Blank Range (of Range)

- An empty cell is also a blank cell but not necessarily the other way around.
- A cell containing `=""` or `'` is blank, but it's not empty (hence the use of the `xlValues` parameter).

**Limitation**

- No merged cells (`Find` method specific).
- No filters (`Find` method specific).
- No hidden cells (rows, columns) (`xlValues` parameter specific).

**The Function**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the range from the first cell
'               of a range to its last cell with a non-blank row or column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefTopLeftNonBlank( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Range
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim Last As Long: Last = rg.Row + rg.Rows.Count - 1 ' worksheet row
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = rg.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - Last + lCell.Row)
        Last = .Column + .Columns.Count - 1 ' worksheet column
        Set lCell = .Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        Set RefTopLeftNonBlank _
            = .Resize(, .Columns.Count - Last + lCell.Column)
    End With
    
End Function
```

**Usage**

```
Sub RefTopLeftNonBlankTEST()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A3:O43")
    Dim tlrg As Range: Set tlrg = RefTopLeftNonBlank(rg)
    If Not tlrg Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print rg.Address(0, 0), tlrg.Address(0, 0)
        rg.Interior.Color = xlNone    
        tlrg.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If 
End Sub
```